# Play MP3 on facebook wall making it impossible to download the file

Tags: facebook

I need a possibility to insert a flash mp3 player on a facebook wall entry. I know I can do this just by posting a mp3 URL or by using fb:mp3, but both make it possible for the user to download. Due to legal reasons this must not be possible.

Can anyone point me to a mp3-player-app that can do this, where the file URL is encrypded / hidden?

Comment: Technically, just by streaming it, you're downloading it to the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/audio.html) has an option to stream the audio so that it cannot be downloaded.  See the section titled "Secure your audio files from direct download".  This should work on Facebook.